# MongoDB group then sort by calculation

Tags: mongodb, sorting, group-by

Every entry in my mongoDB is of the form

```
{"_id" : date,
"tickers" = [{"ticker": ticker, "open": open, "close":close}]
```

where the entire collection is a year of data. I am trying to group by day and then for each day get the ticker with the highest open. Below is my best attempt but it does not seem to work properly.

```
db.stocks.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$tickers'},
  {"$sort": {"_id": 1, "tickers.open": -1}},
  {"$group": {
    "_id": "_id",
    "ticker": { "$first": "$tickers.ticker"},
    "open": { "$first": "$tickers.open" },
    "close": { "$first": "$tickers.close" }
    }}
])
```

Below is an example record of the 252 in the db

```
   {
    "_id" : "19990726",
    "tickers" : [
        {
            "ticker" : "luk",
            "close" : 5.96998,
            "open" : 6.07182
        },
        {
            "ticker" : "cce",
            "close" : 15.0793,
            "open" : 15.2627
        },
        {
            "ticker" : "bac",
            "close" : 22.4244,
            "open" : 21.9815
        },
        {
            "ticker" : "cci",
            "close" : 24.5,
            "open" : 24.19
        },
        {
            "ticker" : "kss",
            "close" : 35.7964,
            "open" : 36.3512
        },
        {
            "ticker" : "luv",
            "close" : 13.0781,
            "open" : 13.2789
        },
        {
            "ticker" : "mwv",
            "close" : 16.5388,
            "open" : 17.0901
        }
    ]
}
```

and when I run my query I only get returned

```
{ "_id" : "_id", "ticker" : "aig", "open" : 812.485, "close" : 829.651 }
```

When I should be getting back one record per "_id" plus a single item from the "tickers" subarray for that record containing the ticker with the max open.

When I attempt to modify the now working query I am messing up the syntax for nesting calculations to calculate the day change rather than the max. Could someone help me nest them properly?

```
    db.stocks.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$tickers'},
  {"$sort": {"_id": 1, {$abs: { 1 - $divide: [ "$tickers.close", "$tickers.open" ] }}: -1}},
  {"$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "ticker": { "$first": "$tickers.ticker"},
    "open": { "$first": "$tickers.open" },
    "close": { "$first": "$tickers.close" }
    }}
]);
```

Comment: Please show a sample set of input data (e.g., a few records per day for 3 or 4 days), the results you are expecting, and the results you are getting currently.  It's hard to know what "does not seem to work properly" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error may be related to the `_id` you are using. You see that is an [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions) that indicates which field you will use to group.

> **Field Path and System Variables**: Aggregation expressions use field path to access fields in the input documents. To specify a field path,
>   use a string that prefixes with a dollar sign $ the field name or the
>   dotted field name, if the field is in embedded document. For example,
>   "$user" to specify the field path for the user field or "$user.name"
>   to specify the field path to "user.name" field.
>
> "$" is equivalent to "$$CURRENT." where the CURRENT is a
>   system variable that defaults to the root of the current object in the
>   most stages, unless stated otherwise in specific stages. CURRENT can
>   be rebound.

I order to make work your query, you need to refer using `$`, for instance `$_id`.

```
db.stocks.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$tickers'},
  {"$sort": {"_id": 1, "tickers.open": -1}},
  {"$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "ticker": { "$first": "$tickers.ticker"},
    "open": { "$first": "$tickers.open" },
    "close": { "$first": "$tickers.close" }
    }}
]);
```

You can see examples of `$group _id` in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly what I was messing up. Is there a way to do this with $max instead?